# How to delete message entities (message stack) of a special template depending on entity age

Tags: 8, message-subscribe

for the "Private Message" module, my Drupal 8 site uses the "Message" module (https://www.drupal.org/project/message) as substructure.

I would like to build a kind of notification center into the page, which should be possible to implement with the message stack (as I heard).

The trigger to generate such a message will probably be a custom module.
The message module also offers a kind of "auto cleanup", but unfortunately as far as I have seen only for all messages and not per message template.

In principle I only want a notification center, which is triggered at certain events and which cleans itself depending on the message type (e.g. only the last 10 messages of a certain template or delete all messages of a certain template which are older than 10 days).

In general, I guess cleanup does not work, as it would probably also delete the "private messages".

Any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to override the cleanup/auto delete settings in the message template configuration (even via UI) per template. Just visit the template configuration form.